# How to format date column to get the day name in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

I have a oracle db and there are two columns so i want to display day ex:(SUNDAY, MONDAY...) according to given date in db.

Table Name: TBL_HOLIDAY_MASTER:

```
     Holiday_date     Description
***********************************
    22-NOV-15       Weekly Holiday
    23-NOV-15       Working Day
    24-NOV-15       Working Day
    29-NOV-15       Weekly Holiday
    30-NOV-15       Working Day
    21-MAY-17       Weekly Holiday
    18-AUG-19       Weekly Holiday
```

I want output Like:-

```
    Holiday_date    Description
*************************************
    SUNDAY          Weekly Holiday
    MONDAY          Working Day
    TUESDAY         Working Day
    SUNDAY          Weekly Holiday
    MONDAY          Working Day
    SUNDAY          Weekly Holiday
    SUNDAY          Weekly Holiday
```

Comment: A google search on "oracle date functions" will provide valuable information.

Comment: Show your original code.

Comment: @sphinks i have not created code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve this with TO_CHAR function with DAY parameter, in your case it would be:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Holiday_date,'DAY') as Holiday_date, Description 
FROM TBL_HOLIDAY_MASTER;
```

Comment: `'DAY'` will have trailing blank spaces, better use `'FMDAY'`.

Comment: Perfect!!! Also we can give 'DY' or 'Dy' instead of 'DAY' to get the day in 3 letters like TUE or Tue respectively

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **TO_CHAR** and **FMDAY** format to get the day name. `FM` is required to remove the **trailing blank spaces**.

```
TO_CHAR(date_column, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
```

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + LEVEL -1, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') "DAYS"
  2  FROM DUAL
  3    CONNECT BY level <= 7;

DAYS
---------
MONDAY
TUESDAY
WEDNESDAY
THURSDAY
FRIDAY
SATURDAY
SUNDAY

7 rows selected.
```